# 'use-strict' enabled but not working in node

Tags: node.js, use-strict

I have enabled `use-strict` mode in my .js file but when I run it, node keeps telling me that I don't have it enabled. PLEASE don't tell me to write `"use-strict";` at the top of my file **because I already tried that**.

Here is my `server.js` file. I have been trying to see what is wrong but so far stack overflow has not been much help since most people seem to get this working on their first try.

```
require('use-strict')
'use-strict';

let util = require('util');
let http = require('http');
let Bot  = require('@kikinteractive/kik');

var kik_username = process.env.KIK_USERNAME;
var kik_api_key = process.env.KIK_API_KEY;
var kik_baseUrl = process.env.KIK_BASEURL;


// Configure the bot API endpoint, details for your bot
let bot = new Bot({
    username: kik_username,
    apiKey: kik_api_key,
    baseUrl: kik_baseUrl
});

bot.updateBotConfiguration();

bot.onTextMessage((message) => {
    message.reply(message.body);
});

// Set up your server and start listening
let server = http.createServer(bot.incoming()).listen(8085);
```

Everything seems fine but when I run

```
$ node server.js
```

I keep getting this error

```
let util = require('util');
^^^

SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:148:18)
    at node.js:405:3
```

It tells me to enable strict mode **BUT I ALREADY DID THAT**. I even required an npm package to make sure I was doing it right! Can anyone make sense of what is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No dash in 'use strict'

```
'use strict' // not 'use-strict'
```

Check out the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) for further reference

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to require an npm package.  just put "use strict"; at the top of the js file.